# How to find nearest road for given latitude and longitude on geometry column

Tags: sql-server-2016, spatial

I have a database with Spatial column of type Geometry. I have a query that takes in a latitude / longitude. I am trying to retrieve all of the roadway details within 0.05 mile of the lat/long address.

Query

```
DECLARE @h geometry;  
SET @h = geometry::Point(-83.45320, 38.7247646, 32123);
SET @h = @h.MakeValid() --Force to valid geometry
SELECT TOP(1000) 
    @h.STGeometryType(),
    @h,
    @h.STDistance([SHAPE]) as Distance, 
    [SHAPE].STGeometryType(),
    [SHAPE].STDistance(@h) as Distance, 
FROM RoadInv
ORDER BY SHAPE.STDistance(@h)
```

Here the result

```
GeoType GeoPoint    DistanceFromPoint   ShapeType   DistanceFromShape
Point   0x7B7D0000010C05A3923A01DD54C036261F16C55C4340  509677.3356 LineString  509677.3356
Point   0x7B7D0000010C05A3923A01DD54C036261F16C55C4340  511355.3753 LineString  511355.3753
Point   0x7B7D0000010C05A3923A01DD54C036261F16C55C4340  511360.4064 LineString  511360.4064
Point   0x7B7D0000010C05A3923A01DD54C036261F16C55C4340  511360.4064 LineString  511360.4064
Point   0x7B7D0000010C05A3923A01DD54C036261F16C55C4340  511362.0417 LineString  511362.0417
```

Not sure if my query is correct! All I want is road within 0.05 mile from my lat/long

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would have use the STBuffer combined to STIntersect

Answer (score 0):

I used the DotSpatial to convert the SRId WGS84 to Ohio state plane south (32123) and then calculate the distance.

Thanks
Venkatesh